# CentOS7 using R to install clusterProfiler get error about openssl

Tags: r, openssl

I've been having an unresolved error when I installed clusterProfiler using R on CentOS7. I have checked the information and some of them say it is the reason for installing the openssl version at the same time, but I have not found a specific solution.

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘openssl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/00LOCK-openssl/00new/openssl/libs/openssl.so':
  libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/openssl’
ERROR: dependency ‘openssl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/httr’
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘europepmc’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/europepmc’
ERROR: dependency ‘europepmc’ is not available for package ‘enrichplot’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/enrichplot’
ERROR: dependency ‘enrichplot’ is not available for package ‘clusterProfiler’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/clusterProfiler’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this operation can solve the problem:

`yum install openssl-devel`

`yum info openssl-devel`

`pkg-config --modversion openssl`